# How to know when someone has commited projects in Tortoise

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Please,

I need to know when developers 'commit' the project, so others developers can be notified about their version need to be updated.

There is some command line to do this?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question... but my team uses a Continuous Integration server (Team City).  Every time there is a check in, Team City updates, builds, runs unit tests, and notifies of success or failure of the unit tests.  The notification can go to the whole team, so they know there is new code.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that one should update often: in the morning at least, and certainly before every commit. If you *really* need this, look into post-commit hooks as a possibility. But how long until they just ignore the annoying messages?

Answer (score 4):

There's a simple tool called CommitMonitor which you can use. It sits in the tray and notifies of new commits. This is windows-only, though.

http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/CommitMonitor.html

Normally, a commit doesn't require everyone else to update immediately. Usually, developers decide themselves when they want to update, because an update in the middle of work will pull you back (i.e. you'll have to do a rebuild, fix merge conflicts in code being worked on etc.)

Comment: The more often you merge other peoples' code, the less trouble it is. If you wait a week to merge, you're going to spend a lot more time figuring out what broke and why.

Comment: That's not usually a problem, because if your code builds successfully and the comitted version builds, too (which you know from the build servers), I very rarelly observe problematic merge conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

We notify the people in tolist.txt via this post-commit hook in Windows, post-commit.cmd:

```
set repo=%1
set rev=%2
set svnlook="svnlook.exe"
if exist "%repo%\hooks\blat" set blat="%repo%\hooks\blat\blat.exe"

:ok

if [%blat%]==[] goto :exitzero

set tmpfile=c:\temp\blat%RANDOM%

:: Build subject line
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in ('svnlook dirs-changed %repo% -r %rev%') do set lev1=%%i&&set lev2=%%j
for /f %%i in ('svnlook author %repo% -r %rev%') do set author=%%i
set subject="%author% committed to %lev1%/%lev2%"

:: Build email text
echo>>%tmpfile% Author, Commit date, Message length, and Message
%svnlook% info %repo% -r %rev% >>%tmpfile%
echo.>>%tmpfile%
echo>>%tmpfile% List of files changed:
%svnlook% changed %repo% -r %rev% >>%tmpfile%

set tolist="%repo%\hooks\tolist.txt"

%blat% -install smtpaddress.company.com myuserid@company.com
%blat% %tmpfile% -tf %tolist% -from Subversion -replyto myuserid@company.com -subject %subject%
del %tmpfile%

:exitzero
exit 0
```

tolist.txt contains a 1-per-line list of userid@company.com email address.

You'll have to download blat and put it in the repository's 'hooks' subdirectories for this command file to work.

Comment: When your team grows, this will probably flood everyones mailbox. Especially if your repository contains multiple projects, not everyone is interrested in all commits.

Comment: @PMF - actually, it doesn't.  We primarily use it to alert our immediate manager/lead programmer to commits.  We are also a repository-per-group shop with small groups.

Comment: Ok, that's a bit of a different story set-up then. We use just a single repository for now about 40 (more-or-less active) developers, easily resulting in some 100-150 commits a week. I would still not say this is a lot, but I wouldn't want to get this many E-Mails, though (even if I can automatically sort them somewhere).